# Content Editable false not working with delete button

Tags: html

I am trying to create an inline editor.

```
<div contentEditable="true">
 <div> <span  contentEditable="false"  >hello</span></div>
 <div > <span  contentEditable="false">world</span></div>
</div>
```

when we move the cursor at front of first text and click delete button, it will remove that text node . Here the hello text div node removing. I need to restrict that, please suggest solution for this.

Comment: You need to remove the attribute alltogether

Answer (score 0):

you can use javascript to prevent delete key event

**Or**   you can use this  make the `contentEditable` elements inside the non editable element

then use `var el=document.getElementById('CtE1').innerText;` to get text

```html
<span id="CtE1"contentEditable="false">
 <span contentEditable="true"></span>hello<span contentEditable="true"></span> World<span contentEditable="true"></span>
</span>
```